# why a simple select sql generate multiple stages in sparksql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a simple spark sql "select * from log_hourly where date = '20180901' and hour='10' limit 2000", but there are multiple stages generated，it is so wired. why there is "exchange" operation?

[image]

Comment: Exchange means shuffling, moving data in some way.

Comment: Try .explain and post this pls. Looks easy to follow, but indeed thin on detail.

Comment: run the query with .explain(true) - add this and share the output, that will help us analyze I think. E.g. spark.sql("select * from trips where device = 89765 and time_asc = 5 limit 2000").explain(true)

Comment: Providing data does help.

Comment: Solved? Can you provide the info requested?